# Get value from array based on key value and changing size

Tags: javascript

How do I get the *answers* for the question with value "Second question in category 2?"?

I need to do this with JavaScript. The category names will be random, although I do know this value as well as the value for the question I am looking for the answers to.

The number of categories and questions will vary so the solution must not rely on a fixed size to this array.

There will not be any duplicate categories or questions.

Any help will be awesome I have been struggling with this. What is getting me is that category names are changing and I'm not sure how to match a value.

**js**

```
{
    "Category 1":[
        {
            "question":"Fist question in category 1?",
            "answers":[
                "first answer",
                "second answer",
                "third answer",
                "fourth answer"
            ]
        },
        {
            "question":"Second question in category 1?",
            "answers":[
                "first answer",
                "second answer",
                "third answer",
                "fourth answer"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Category 2":[
        {
            "question":"First question in category 2?",
            "answers":[
                "first answer",
                "second answer",
                "third answer",
                "fourth answer"
            ]
        },
        {
            "question":"Second question in category 2?",
            "answers":[
                "first answer",
                "second answer",
                "third answer",
                "fourth answer"
            ]
        },
        {
            "question":"Third question in category 2?",
            "answers":[
                "first answer",
                "second answer",
                "third answer",
                "fourth answer"
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Are you ok with using a library to do it?

Comment: Just some simple for loops should do the trick... I don't see how a library would help

Comment: @khang - why would he want a library when the functionality he needs is built in natively and relatively easy to implement? for loops are powerful.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `for...in` loop.

```
var obj = {/* Assume that this is your object */};
for (let key in obj){ //Loops through object
    for (let i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++){ //Loops through array
        if (obj[key][i].question == "Second question in category 2?"){
            var answers = obj[key][i].answers; //Here's your answers in array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked well. I had to change let to var but otherwise it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Do a for in loop on the categories and then another for in loop for each category.

```
for (var i in categories) {
    var category = categories[i];
    for (var k in category) {
        if (category[k].question == 'First question in category 2?') {
            console.log(category[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for-in` to loop over arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var questions = {
            "Category 1": [
            {
                "question": "Fist question in category 1?",
                "answers": ["first answer",
                "second answer",
                "third answer",
                "fourth answer"]
            },
                {
                    "question": "Second question in category 1?",
                    "answers": ["first answer",
                    "second answer",
                    "third answer",
                    "fourth answer"]
                }],
            "Category 2": [
                {
                    "question": "First question in category 2?",
                    "answers": ["first answer",
                    "second answer",
                    "third answer",
                    "fourth answer"]
                },
                 {
                     "question": "Second question in category 2?",
                     "answers": ["first answer",
                     "second answer",
                     "third answer",
                     "fourth answer"]
                 },
                 {
                     "question": "Third question in category 2?",
                     "answers": ["first answer",
                     "second answer",
                     "third answer",
                     "fourth answer"]
                 }]
        };
        for(var category in questions)
        {
            var filtered = $.grep(questions[category], function (e, i) {
                return e.question == "Second question in category 2?";
            });
            if(filtered.length > 0)
            {
                console.log(filtered[0].answers);
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP doesn't mention jquery and native javascript would handle this with ease

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
const obj = {
    "Category 1": [{
        "question": "Fist question in category 1?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Second question in category 1?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }],
    "Category 2": [{
        "question": "First question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Second question in category 2?",
        "answers": [ "first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer",
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Third question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }]
};

const values = Object.values(obj);

const result = values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  Array.prototype.push.apply(acc, cur);
  return acc;
}, []).filter(obj => obj.question === 'Third question in category 2?');

console.log(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple solution using **forEach** on each array. Hope it helps!

```js
var obj = {
    "Category 1": [{
        "question": "Fist question in category 1?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Second question in category 1?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }],

    "Category 2": [{
        "question": "First question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Second question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Third question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }]
};

for(var i in obj){
    obj[i].forEach(function(x){
        if(x.question === "Second question in category 2?"){
         console.log(x.answers);
      }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using for loops,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="getAnswers"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var qas={
    "Category 1": [{
        "question": "Fist question in category 1?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Second question in category 1?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }],
    "Category 2": [{
        "question": "First question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Second question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }, {
        "question": "Third question in category 2?",
        "answers": ["first answer",
            "second answer",
            "third answer",
            "fourth answer"
        ]
    }]
};

for(obj in qas){
 var qasobj=qas[obj];
 for(categ in qasobj){
  console.log("getting second"+qasobj[categ].question);
  if(qasobj[categ].question=="Second question in category 2?"){
   console.log("You have got your answers "+qasobj[categ].answers);
   document.getElementById("getAnswers").innerHTML=qasobj[categ].answers;
  }
 }
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var questions = {
  "Category 1": [{
    "question": "Fist question in category 1?",
    "answers": ["first answer",
      "second answer",
      "third answer",
      "fourth answer"
    ]
  }, {
    "question": "Second question in category 1?",
    "answers": ["first answer",
      "second answer",
      "third answer",
      "fourth answer"
    ]
  }],
  "Category 2": [{
    "question": "First question in category 2?",
    "answers": ["first answer",
      "second answer",
      "third answer",
      "fourth answer"
    ]
  }, {
    "question": "Second question in category 2?",
    "answers": ["first answer",
      "second answer",
      "third answer",
      "fourth answer"
    ]
  }, {
    "question": "Third question in category 2?",
    "answers": ["first answer - 1",
      "second answer",
      "third answer",
      "fourth answer"
    ]
  }]
};


function getAnswer(inputQuestion) {
  var output = {};

  Object.keys(questions).forEach((category) => {
    questions[category].forEach((val) => {
      if (val.question === inputQuestion) {
        output = val.answers;
      }
    });
  });
  return output;
}


var answer = getAnswer("Third question in category 2?");
console.log(answer);
```